# No configuration file found when using log4j with log4j2 in project?

Tags: junit, junit4, log4j2

In our project we are using log4j with log4j2. When I run the Junits I am getting the error saying: `No log4j2 configuration file found.`

But the log4j.properties file is already available in that location. Using `Google` I found that it requires logj2.xml file then I provided log4j2.xml file. Junits runs smoothly.

Does log4j2 support property file or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4j2 does support property file.

Property file can be provided to log4j2 by either of the following 2 ways:

- Set the configuration file path (with `.properties` extension) in `"log4j.configurationFile"` system property.
- Name the configuration file `log4j2.properties` (or `log4j2-test.properties`) and keep that in the classpath.

You can learn more about log4j2 configuration [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).